# Using opentelemetry for Users, Sessions and Events of Application Insights

Tags: azure

I am using Python in my project. From what I see in the documentation, Users, Sessions and Events sections of Application Insights takes data from customEvents table to make their metrics. But I can make records to customEvents only by using OpenCensus. Does that mean there is way to use Sessions and Events of Application Insights if I collect data by opentelemetry?